# Splitting value of a dictionary into two dataframe columns based on a comma in the value

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, dictionary

Hi I have a dictionary below,

I want to split the dictionary value into two based on a comma present in the dictionary value, and then store the result in a new dataframe as follows:

For a particular dictionary entry, lets say the first one in our case:

(1, 5) - this is the key, and should be column 1 in a new dataframe
(2,) - this is extracted from the value (pre-comma), and should be column 2 in the dataframe
1.0 - this is extracted from the value (post-comma), and should be column 3 in the dataframe

The same process should be repeated for all (4 in this case) key value pairs in the dictionary.

If rules is the name of the dictionary,
I know I can access rules.keys(), and rules.values(), but what I do not understand is how do I access the comma split values in the dictionary because when I try something like rules.values() [1], it throws an error.

```
{(1, 5): ((2,), 1.0),
 (2, 5): ((1,), 1.0),
 (4,): ((2,), 1.0),
 (5,): ((1, 2), 1.0)}
```

Output DF:

```
Col 1       Col2        Col3
(1, 5)      (2,)        1.0
(2, 5)      (1,)        1.0
(4,)        (2,)        1.0
(5,)        (1, 2)      1.0
```

Comment: Can you post the output DF?

Comment: I just posted it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a list comprehension.

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {(1, 5): ((2,), 1.0), (2, 5): ((1,), 1.0), (5,): ((1, 2), 1.0), (4,): ((2,), 1.0)}
df = pd.DataFrame([[k] + list(v) for k, v in data.items()], columns=["Col_1", "Col_2", "Col_3"])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
    Col_1   Col_2  Col_3
0  (1, 5)    (2,)    1.0
1  (2, 5)    (1,)    1.0
2    (5,)  (1, 2)    1.0
3    (4,)    (2,)    1.0
```